# Bootstrap Div or Span like form-group input-group-addon

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, layout

Is it possible to make something like the form-group input-group-addon layout just to display information? Not to use it in a form.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Firstname</span>
        <input value="Vincent" name="InputFirstname" type="text" required>
    </div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  height:30px;
  padding-left:10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v69ju4Lz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to worrk well on Chrome. It doesn't require a new CSS class but it does use one already provided by Bootstrap.

```
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text">Firstname</span>
  </div>
  <span class="form-control">Vincent</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Firstname</span>
        <span class="value">Vincent</span>
    </div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.value {
  display:block;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  height:30px;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}
```